# Inlude Module independ JS file in module blade file in laravel

Tags: laravel-10

I created multiple Modules in my script, Each module have their own JS, Images, CSS file inside resources assets folder of that particular module, Like in I have user module on below path in larval

Modules\User
And my JS file is inside
Modules\User\Resources\assets\js\edit.js

How I can include this same file in my create.blade.php file?

If I am trying with 
Its not getting work, Also I don't want to move it to public folder, as its own to particular module. Please anybody help me to short out this issue.

Thanks

I tried to use   in blade file, but its getting public folder assets path in this. And not including my module folder asset path.